# Can we implement this Captcha in siebel

Tags: captcha, siebel

Hi I would like to try Captcha in Siebel Application.

Is there any 3rd party appliaction for thyese Captcha so tha i can integrate it with siebel.
If any such a site is there please share it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question! But since this could be useful for someone in future, I am answering it..

I would suggest you to invoke external dll..

```
Set objTime = CreateObject("SAMPLE_PRJ_NAME.SAMPLE_CLASS_NAME")
objTime.METHOD_NAME
```

You can find sample VB code from here:
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?645886-Captcha-Generator